# How to take the enumeration away from my Reference?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to take these numbers away from my reference list.

[image]

Is it possible?

The code I use for my reference is:

```
\usepackage[sorting = anyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{References}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you lots!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you load `biblatex` without explicitly passing the `style` option, you get the default `style=numeric,`, which cites numerically and has the numeric citation labels in the bibliography (how else would you tell which reference is which?).

You can select a different style, for example

```
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
```

or

```
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
```

then the bibliography will not feature numeric citation labels.